# Species richness: Why does the more species at one plot imply the more species are missed?

Tags: jackknife

Species richness: Why does the more species at one plot imply the more species are missed?

This is what my lecture notes say.

> The more there are species that have been observed only once, the more
> one can assume that observations of species have been missed.

This sounds counterintuitive, but perhaps the idea is that if one plot has "such many", then it's likely that the rest have also "such many".

I.e. e.g. if one plot out of 20 plots has 32 species, then in the worst case it's possible that the remaning 19 plots also each have ~32 new species. And the total would be e.g. 608 species, while having most species "only once observed" would suggest that it's 32 + something.

Comment: This seems more ecology than statistics. Observations are usually limited in several ways, area scanned, time spent observing, whether organisms can hide, the knowledge of the observer. It's one thing to look at a small quadrat and count every small plant visible and another thing to lurk in a tropical forest and try to count every distinct bird flying around.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about "more species", it is about "more *rare* species".

If you keep finding species that occur only once (only in one plot or maybe only one individual), that suggests that you might be dealing with a community that is rich in rare species. So you can assume that if you would establish new plots between the existing ones, you would keep finding more of those rare species that you've missed before.

See also: [Species–area relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species%E2%80%93area_relationship) and how that affect your study design in terms of plot size/number.

Comment: If it's this way, then my lecture notes have sloppy wording. There's no mention of rarity, but count.

Comment: It is there, in "The more there are species that have been observed only once […]": a count of rare species. That sounds like the very condensed language somebody would use on a lecture slide, so you probably just wrote it down as it was on the slide. It is correct, but difficult to understand if you don't already know what it means.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for the hint, I've edited that. Apologies to OP if that sounded harsh!